# Odoo 8 Fields different models

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I currently struggle with fields in odoo. I'm pretty new to odoo so it would be very nice to have an overview over the whole fields/inheritance stuff. Just picture the following scenario: Module A has some fields that I'd like to display in Module B. For that purpose I'm developing Module C.

How can I read a field from Module A?
How can I create a field in Module B?
How can I assign the field in Module B the content of the Field in Module A?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are not very clear.

However, let's say that in Module A there's a class called classA.
In Module B there's a class called classB.
You want to show the fields of classA in classB, then you need some connection between them.

In your module C, create a class called classC in which you inherit classB and add a relation field that will create this kind of connection.

This can be achieved by **Relational fields**. You can either read the documentation.
[https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html](http://Relational%20Field%20Odoo%20documentation)
or this link
http://findnerd.com/list/view/Create-many2one-and-one2many-relationship-in-OpenERP/508/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the basic idea behind it, however I have no clue how to implement this. Could you maybe make an example?

Let's assume I created a boolean field (x_blacklist) in res.partner and want it to be displayed in the account.invoice.tree view, so that I can filter for invoices, made from customers on the blacklist.
Thank you

Comment: **Got it working** Nevermind my comment above. Works now using fields.XXX(related='MANY2ONE.Field'). Thank you so much for your support.